# how to define a struct with a typedef

Tags: c, typedef

I am trying to do the following:

```
typedef struct tagSTRUCT
{
    MYPROC lpfnMyProc;
} STRUCT, *HSTRUCT;

typedef void (*MYPROC)(HSTRUCT);

void version1(HSTRUCT ); // version of delegate MYPROC
void version2(HSTRUCT ); // another version
...
```

, which gives me a compilation error. I have tried to make the typedef of 'MYPROC' before the struct typedef but got too a compilation error. I have tried to use a forward declaration of struct and got also a compilation error:

```
struct tagSTRUCT;
typedef tagSTRUCT STRUCT, *HSTRUCT;
typedef void (*MYPROC)(HSTRUCT );
struct tagSTRUCT
{
   MYPROC lpfnMyProc;
};
```

What should I do?

Comment: Forward declaration is no use, since `STRUCT` has an actual `MYPROC` member, and so `MYPROC` needs to be a complete type.

Comment: @KerrekSB But `MYPROC` can be defined just fine with a forward-declared `tagSTRUCT`, no? …

Comment: @KonradRudolph: `MYPROC` is just a typedef, so it doesn't get any definition at all...

Comment: @KerrekSB Err, yes. Anyway, your answer is exactly what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
typedef struct tagSTRUCT *HSTRUCT;
typedef void (*MYPROC)(HSTRUCT);

typedef struct tagSTRUCT
{
    MYPROC lpfnMyProc;
} STRUCT;
```

This way you can still refer to it as `HSTRUCT`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
struct tagSTRUCT;

typedef void (*MYPROC)(struct tagSTRUCT *);

typedef struct tagSTRUCT {
    MYPROC p;
} STRUCT, * HSTRUCT;
```

Comment: If I could choose more than one best answer !!

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird cyclical dependacy, but the following might work:

```
struct tagSTRUCT;
typedef struct tagSTRUCT *HSTRUCT;
typedef void (*MYPROC)(HSTRUCT*);

typedef struct tagSTRUCT
{
    MYPROC lpfnMyProc;
} STRUCT, *HSTRUCT;

void version1(HSTRUCT ); // version of delegate MYPROC
void version2(HSTRUCT ); // another version
```

Comment: If I could choose more than one best answer !!